# Creating an infinite looping carousel loot box but the infinite loop feature is not working

Tags: javascript

JavaScript:

```
// JavaScript code for the carousel and loot box functionality
const itemsList = [
    {
        name: "Adilette",
        cost: 10000,
        imageSource: "/storage/images/16870804910.jpg",
    },
    {
        name: "Basket profi",
        cost: 20000,
        imageSource: "/storage/images/16870804781.jpg",
    },
    {
        name: "Gazelle",
        cost: 2312,
        imageSource: "/storage/images/16870801082.jpg",
    },
    {
        name: "ZX",
        cost: 23,
        imageSource: "/storage/images/16870804783.jpg",
    },
    {
        name: "Puremotion",
        cost: 23,
        imageSource: "/storage/images/16870805354.jpg",
    },
];

var inRoll = false;
var startTime;

function Roll() {
    // CSS adjustments for the product info
    $('.product-version-2 .product-info').css({
        'margin': '0px auto 0',
        'transition': 'margin 0.5s ease'
    });

    if (inRoll) return;

    inRoll = true;
    document.querySelector(".prize").classList.remove("active");
    let translate = 0;

    startTime = new Date().getTime();
    let move = setInterval(() => {
        let currentTime = new Date().getTime();
        let elapsedTime = currentTime - startTime;

        translate += 10;

        if (translate > 1800) {
            translate = 0;
        }

        items.forEach((e) => (e.style.transform = "translateX(" + -1 * translate + "px)"));

        if (elapsedTime >= 5000) {
            ShowWinner("Basket profi");
        }
    }, 10);


}
```

When attempting to create a smooth infinite loop for my carousel, I set the translate value to 0, but it doesn't produce the desired smooth looping effect.

Despite multiple attempts to modify the code, I'm unable to achieve the desired outcome for my carousel-based loot box. The issue lies in the implementation of the infinite looping mechanism. Currently, when the translate value exceeds 1800, it is reset back to 0, resulting in a disruption in the smooth looping effect.